# Send document to telegram bot using python-telegram-bot Package

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am try to build a telegram bot using python with python-telegram-bot Package and its working with text commands now i try to send a document to user

my code like

```
def start(update, context):

return update.message.download(open('cv.pdf', 'rb'))
```

but it show a error like `return update.message.download(open('cv.pdf', 'rb')) AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'download'`

Then how to send a document file to user any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[telegram.Message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html)

There is no download attribute for the message object, but the bot object has a [send_document](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_document) attribute so to successfully send a document.

```
doc_file = open('cv.pdf', 'rb')
chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
return context.bot.send_document(chat_id, doc_file)
```

Comment: show this error return context.bot.send_document(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, doc_file)
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: try this way chat_id=update.effective_chat.id return context.bot.send_document(chat_id, doc_file) , its working

Comment: Okay that's interesting, I have updated the answer if it solves your question mark it as answered.